# Verify proof: compact iff finite with discrete metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the discrete metric $d$, i.e., 
$$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x = y \\ 1 &\text{ if } x \neq y \end{cases}$$
Using the open cover definition of compactness, show that $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if $X$ is a finite set.

Could someone verify whether my proof is correct or not?

First for the ($\implies$) direction. Assume that $X$ is compact, then every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Consider the particular open cover $U_{\varepsilon} = \{B_{\varepsilon}(x) : x \in X\}$ for $0<\varepsilon<1$. Then there exists $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ such that $X \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(x_1) \cup \cdots \cup B_{\varepsilon}(x_n)$. But $B_{\varepsilon}(x_i) = \{x_i\}$ for $i=1, \cdots, n$ because we have the discrete metric. So $X \subseteq \{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ and hence $X$ must be finite.

For the ($\impliedby$ ) direction. Assume $X$ is finite, i.e., $X = \{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$. Now let $U = \{U_{\lambda} : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be any open cover for $X$. This means that $x_i \in U_{\lambda_i}$ for some $\lambda_i \in \Lambda$ for all $i = 1, \cdots, n$. So $X \subseteq U_{\lambda_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{\lambda_n}$ and so we have produced a finite subcover.

Comment: Your proof is completely right. Go ahed.

Comment: I would like to note that there is virtually no reference to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the proof. Also, if you know some set topology, you can show this is still true if $X$ is a general discrete space.

Comment: (1). Any finite subset of any space is compact....(2). With the discrete metric on  any set $S$, we have $B_1(x)=\{x\}$ for any $x\in S$, so if $\phi \ne A\subset S$ then $C=\{B_1(x):x\in A\}=\{\{x\}:x\in A\}$ is an irreducible open cover of $A. $ That is, no proper subset of $C$ is a cover of $A.$ So $A$ is compact iff $C$ is finite iff $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

In the second part, since $X $ is finite,  you can take, for each $x\in X$, one open set $U_x$, containing $x$, and you will have a finite subcover.

This is a pretty easy result; and I'd say your proof is fine...

The point I think is that when the points are open sets,  you obviously can't have infinitely many of them, or else you have an infinite cover with no finite subcover. ..

Comment: @BarryCipra It's a mistake on my part.